# Спарсить лишь текст с помощью PHP Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, парсер

Использую PHP Simple Html Dom для получения содержимого div'a, значение получаю, все в порядке, но дело в том, что значение передается вместе с html, то есть уже с тем дизайном, которым установлен на сайте источнике. Можно ли как нибудь вытянуть лишь содержимое в виде текста, чтоб я мог самостоятельно изменять дизайн?

Код:

```
<?php

require 'simple_html_dom.php'; //подключаем библиотеку


$html = file_get_html('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/');


$cases =  $html->find('.maincounter-number', 0);

echo '<span style="color: red">'.$cases.'</span>';


?>
```

Comment: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm

Comment: есть же дока  по библиотеке  см . Element methods & properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цитата из [**оф.доки**](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm) *(блок DOM methods & properties)*:

> plaintext - возвращает содержимое, извлеченное из HTML.

Т.е., подставьте свойство *plaintext*: `$html->find('.maincounter-number', 0)->plaintext`

Лишние пробелы можно удалить с помощью штатной ф-ции `trim()`:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/');

$cases = trim($html->find('.maincounter-number', 0)->plaintext);

echo '<span style="color: red">' . $cases . '</span>';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!